# Question concerning Ebola Patent

Tags: method

This is a question concerning patent [ca2741523a1](http://www.google.com/patents/CA2741523A1?cl=en).

Okay, now that Ebola is breaking out and spreading everywhere I want to know if this patent which publicly lists compositions and methods thereof for creating an ebola virus could be used by scientists to create Ebola.

I do not know enough about genetic virus programming to know if the information publicly listed on this patent is enough information to know how to create the biological warfare weapon of mass destruction known as ebola.  Since this is publicly listed on the Internet my query is to inquire whether or not this public information is enough to enable any standard genetic scientists to construct this weapon ebola just by looking up the patent information on google or whether it is not enough information to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of this ebola-related patent of the US government?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-ebola-related-patent-of-the-us-government)

Comment: The patent is not about creating it -- but about how to isolate it -- which is useful for research into ebola and how to create counter measures against it.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question.  This has been incredibly helpful, especially the link. (OP)